# Last node handle goes out of scope but callbacks still work. Why?

Tags: ros, nodehandle

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I thought I need to keep my node handle alive by storing it in my class member, but when I make it a local variable in my constructor and let it go out of scope, my callback still gets called.

Is this proper defined behavior?

```
#include <ros/ros.h>
#include <std_msgs/Int32.h>

class MyNode
{

public:

    MyNode()
    {
        ros::NodeHandle nh; // will go out of scope
        subscriber = nh.subscribe("topic_name", 10, &MyNode::callback, this);
    }

private:

    void callback(std_msgs::Int32ConstPtr const & msg)
    {
        ROS_ERROR_STREAM("Callback got called");
    }

    // I thought this was mandatory
    // ros::NodeHandle nh;

    ros::Subscriber subscriber;

};

int main(int argc, char ** argv)
{
    ros::init(argc, argv, "my_node");
    MyNode node;
    ros::spin();
    return 0;
}
```

**UPDATE:**

[Here](http://wiki.ros.org/roscpp/Overview/Initialization%20and%20Shutdown#Starting_the_roscpp_Node) it says "when the last `ros::NodeHandle` is destroyed, it will call `ros::shutdown()`". Further down it is suggested, that `ros::shutdown()` will make `ros::spin()` return. So what's up with that?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/241861/last-node-handle-goes-out-of-scope-but-callbacks-still-work.-why?/) by [Dimitri Schachmann](https://answers.ros.org/users/22775/dimitri-schachmann/) on ROS Answers with karma: 789 on 2016-08-17

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

If you look at https://github.com/ros/ros_comm/blob/kinetic-devel/clients/roscpp/src/libros/subscriber.cpp#L66, the Subscriber keeps a copy/reference to the node handle. So as long as it exists, there is yet another referenced handle that will prevent the node to shut down.

---

Originally posted by [dseifert](https://answers.ros.org/users/24478/dseifert/) with karma: 106 on 2016-08-18

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3